# ¿Como usar Flask Python en github actions para servir una app web?

Tags: python-3.x, github-pages, github-actions

He decidido usar github action para mostrar mi pagina web y formatearla usando Python Flask, pero no logro hacer que funcione... todo sale bien, no hay errores y flask se queda a la escucha en el puerto de producción(0.0.0.0), pero pareciera que no escucha nada, voy a la url de github page que hice y nada, como si no tuviera escuchando nada ni enviando peticiones.
Aquí esta mi código YML:

```
name: page
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is testing out GitHub Actions 
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
permissions:
  contents: "write"
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production
    steps:
      - name: Installing dependencies
        run: python -m pip install Flask
      - run: echo "Iniciando..."
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - run: echo "Creando servidor..."
      - name: Init server
        run: python "${{ github.workspace }}/server.py"
```

Aquí esta mi código Python:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Blueprint, render_template;
app = Flask(__name__);
DEBUG=False;
#Registramos una nueva url
media_pt=Blueprint("media", __name__, static_folder="./media", static_url_path="/media");
app.register_blueprint(media_pt);

media_pt=Blueprint("static", __name__, static_folder="./static", static_url_path="/static");
app.register_blueprint(media_pt);

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html");
@app.route("/ok")
def is_of():
    return "is okk";
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0",debug=DEBUG)
```

Al principio sin importar que me daba error 404 la pagina de github page, ahora que configure la raíz del proyecto solo me retorna el archivo readme(por no conseguir el index.html)